# C++: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class

I have an assignment for school to create an application which manages a cat shelter and I must provide the option to filter the cats based on certain criteria.

I have a base class Filter, and two derived classes for filtering the cats by age and by breed.

```
class Filter
{
public:
    virtual bool operator()(const Cat & cat) const = 0;
    virtual ~Filter() {}
};


class FilterOfBreed : public Filter
{
private:
    std::string breed;
public:
    FilterOfBreed(const std::string & b) : breed(b) {}
    bool operator()(const Cat & cat) const override { return this->breed.length() == 0 || this->breed == cat.getBreed(); }
};


class FilterAgeLessThan : public Filter
{
private:
    int age;
public:
    FilterAgeLessThan(int a) : age(a) {}
    bool operator()(const Cat & cat) const override { return cat.getAge() <= this->age; }
};
```

And in my Controller, I have the filter function, which filters using copy_if.

```
vector<Cat> Controller::filter(const Filter * filter)
{
    vector<Cat> result;
    copy_if(this->repo.getCats().begin(), this->repo.getCats().end(), back_inserter(result), filter);

    return result;
}
```

I want to be able to call the filter function from the Controller with different types of filtering.
For example:

```
Filter * filter = new FilterOfBreed("Birman");
vector<Cat> filtered = ctrl.filter(filter);
```

filtered should contain the cats of breed Birman.

Or for the following code:

```
Filter * filter = new FilterAgeLessThan(3);
vector<Cat> filtered = ctrl.filter(filter);
```

filtered should contain the cats that have the age less or equal to 3.

For doing the filtering, I need a function which receives two parameters and checks if there's a certain relationship between them. But the function "copy_if" must receive a unary predicate as last argument. I read on a post here that I can use a pointer to a class in copy_if (which has the additional parameters as members), and overload the operator() of that class. Which is why I created the class Filter.

But when I compile the code, it gives me the error: "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments". The error comes from the function "copy_if".

Comment: Hi, I see you posted your code, that's a good thing. Nevertheless, the re-open procedure is often very slow. I think it's best that you delete this question and ask it again so it will get some more attention.

Comment: It is very confusing having a variable with the same name as a method.

Comment: @M.M: Passing by value would not work, since it would attempt to slice the object, and even that would fail because `Filter` is an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

`std::copy_if` accepts a reference to a callable object, not a pointer to it.  You basically have two options:

1. Without changing your function signature, make a reference and pass it to `copy_if`:

   ```
   vector<Cat> Controller::filter(const Filter * filter)
   {
       vector<Cat> result;
       copy_if(repo.getCats().begin(), repo.getCats().end(),
               back_inserter(result), *filter);
       //   THIS ASTERISK IS THE KEY ^^^

       return result;
   }
   ```
2. Change your function to take a reference just like `copy_if`:

   ```
   vector<Cat> Controller::filter(const Filter & filter)
       //           CHANGED TO AMPERSAND HERE ^^^
   {
       vector<Cat> result;
       copy_if(repo.getCats().begin(), repo.getCats().end(),
               back_inserter(result), filter);

       return result;
   }
   ```

Contrary to a now-deleted comment, passing by value is NOT an option.  Polymorphism only works with pointers and references, not copies.

Also, using a base class for function objects is out of vogue.  Modern C++ style will generally use a lambda for this:

```
vector<Cat> filtered =
     ctrl.filter([](const Cat& cat){ return cat.getBreed() == "Birman"; });
```

To make that work, you can either

1. Make your filter function a template that can accept the lambda type:

   ```
   template<typename Predicate>
   vector<Cat> Controller::filter(const Predicate & filter)
   {
       vector<Cat> result;
       copy_if(repo.getCats().begin(), repo.getCats().end(),
               back_inserter(result), filter);

       return result;
   }
   ```
2. Use `std::function` which does type erasure, which is nearly the same as polymorphism but doesn't require inheritance:

   ```
   vector<Cat> Controller::filter(std::function<bool(const Cat&)> filter)
   {
       vector<Cat> result;
       copy_if(repo.getCats().begin(), repo.getCats().end(),
               back_inserter(result), filter);

       return result;
   }
   ```

Both of these will still accept the `Filter`-derived invocation, too.